# How do you set dynamics crm look up field value to null?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Sometimes when we want to migrate data from SQL database to dynamics CRM, there are some column with null value. And the record which contains null column wouldn't be created in CRM. So, I think I need to put some condition in order to create record in CRM with null value from database. Take a look what I have tried:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i][8].ToString()))
     {
         Guid hubid = new Guid(dt.Rows[i][8].ToString());
         rs["new_hubid"] = new EntityReference("new_hub", hubid);
     }
     else
     {
         **Solution 1**: rs["new_hubid"] = new EntityReference("new_hub", null);
         **Solution 2**: rs["new_hubid"] = null;
     }
    service.Create(rs);
```

From solution 1 and solution 2, which one is work best for you to set look up value to null ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2 is the correct way for clearing an EntityReference.

As a side-note, you might want to look into generating [early bound entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx) to avoid difficult to maintain code such as `dt.Rows[i][8].ToString()`.

Comment: You are being picky now, as long as the user knows that 8th column is a GUID and 28th column is a bit field, just like 23rd 17th and 19th columns are all strings, I do not see a problem with dt.rows[i][8].